# .NET StreamReader Won't Close

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, rtf, streamreader

I'm using a RTF file as a template for an ASP.NET web application. My VB.NET code reads the file using a StreamReader, replaces some strings, and creates a new Word document with data from the database. My code closes and disposes of the StreamReader. However, when I attempt to upload a revised RTF file to the web server I get an error, "Cannot open the file for writing". So obviously the file remains open long after the ASP.NET page has run.

How can I force the StreamReader to close? Even editing the web.config file to force the web application to restart isn't enough to kill the lock on this file.

Comment: If you close and dispose that seems strange, can you paste some sample code?

Comment: I agree. Are there any there stream operations going on here?

Comment: I have a development web site which is opening a file in the production web site. It seems I have to edit the web.config in the production web site to restart the web application and release the file even though it is the development web site that opened it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

consider using the "using" idiom, also available in VB.net

```
using(StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(...)) {

}
```

the stream will get closed, even if exception is thrown

Consider closing all IDisposable implementations like this

Answer (score 1):

It seems odd if it's hanging on even after a close/dispose.  Are you using a FileStream along with the StreamReader?  Generally, I use a FileStream to control access to the file and feed that to the StreamReader, a la:

```
FileStream fsIn = new FileStream("path",FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None);
StreamReader srIn = new StreamReader(fsIn, System.Text.Encoding.Default);

//...do stuff....

srIn.close();
srIn.Dispose();
fsIn.close();
fsIn.Dispose();
```

Better yet, if you're limiting the use of your StreamReader to one method, stick the Close/Dispose in a Finally.

Comment: I would also suggest to use "using" directive.

Comment: What can I say?  I'm old fashioned :-)

Comment: That makes me think that I never really tested if Dispose() closes the stream, but I trust the documentation!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the stream is closed in finally.

```
FileStream fsIn = null;
StreamReader srIn = null; 

try
{
  fsIn = new FileStream("path",FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None);
  srIn = new StreamReader(fsIn, System.Text.Encoding.Default);

  //...do stuff....

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
}
finally
{
  srIn.close();
  srIn.Dispose();
  fsIn.close();
  fsIn.Dispose();
}
```